# I want to place a scrollbar on the bottom of the screen but I get an error: object has no attribute 'xview'

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want to place a `Scrollbar` at the bottom of the screen. The error I get is: object has no attribute 'xview'. Now I understand that this means that the grid must be placed at a separate line. But I can't find the wrong code. Can someone tell me what have I done wrong?

```py
    my_w = tk.Tk()
    my_w.geometry("1514x380")
    my_w.resizable(False, False)
    my_w.configure(bg='#2e7287')
    my_w.title('Openbare Verlichting Administratie record lijst')
    def my_display(offset):

        #Add a Horizontal Scrollbar
        scroll_h = Scrollbar(my_w, orient= HORIZONTAL)
        scroll_h.grid(row=31,column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)  #pack(side= BOTTOM, fill= "x")

        q="SELECT * from masten order by project asc LIMIT "+ str(offset) +","+str(limit)
        r_set=my_conn.execute(q);
        i=0 # row value inside the loop 
        for persoon in r_set: 
            for j in range(len(persoon)):
                e = Entry(my_w, width=13, fg='black',bg="#86b9d4", font=("Arial",6)) 
                e.grid(row=i, column=j) 
                e.insert(END, persoon[j])
            i=i+1
        while (i<limit): # required to blank the balance rows if they are less 
            for j in range(len(persoon)):
                e = Entry(my_w, width=13, fg='black',bg="#86b9d4", font=("Arial",6)) 
                e.grid(row=i, column=j) 
                e.insert(END, "")
            i=i+1
    # Show buttons 
        back = offset - limit # This value is used by Previous button
        next = offset + limit # This value is used by Next button       
        b1 = tk.Button(my_w, text='----->',bg="#a6897c", fg="#000080", font=("Arial",12), 
        disabledforeground="red", activebackground='#2e7287', command=lambda: my_display(next))
        b1.grid(row=30,column=13)

        b2 = tk.Button(my_w, text='<-----', bg="#a6897c", fg="#000080", font=("Arial",12), 
        disabledforeground="red",  activebackground='#2e7287', command=lambda: my_display(back))
        b2.grid(row=30,column=11)

        b3 = tk.Button(my_w, text='Stop', bg="#a6897c", fg="#000080", font=("Arial",12), 
        disabledforeground="red",  activebackground='#2e7287', command=my_w.destroy)
        b3.grid(row=30,column=15)



        if(no_rec <= next): 
            b1["state"]="disabled" # disable next button
        else:
            b1["state"]="active"  # enable next button
        
        if(back >= 0):
            b2["state"]="active"  # enable Prev button
        else:
            b2["state"]="disabled"# disable Prev button
            
        #Attact the scrollbar with the text widget
        scroll_h.config(command = my_w.xview)
    my_w.config(xscrollcommand=scroll_h.set)
        
    my_display(0)        
    my_w.mainloop()
```

Comment: You haven't even defined the `limit` variable and `my_conn` variable, how do you expect anyone to fix this code? There are way too many Syntax and Runtime errors. Please try to be clear with your code, and convey what you want to achieve, what is actually happening, just don't post code and wait for someone god-like to guess what you want to achieve and help you. This isn't any insult, but since you are new, you need to know how to ask questions here to not get question-banned like me.

Comment: `Tk()` does not support scrolling.